# Which Area 51 proposals are migration proposals?

Tags: discussion, area-51

There have been several question about the process of migrating Stack Exchange 1.0 sites to the Stack Exchange 2.0 system. I thought it might be useful to create a list of Area 51 proposals that are migration candidates, i.e. have a posted comment along the lines of "this is a replacement for x" where x is a Stack Exchange 1.0 site.

Answer (score 10):

I have no access to information that could tell me definitely that a site will or will not be migrated. All I can do is list those for which a migration has been suggested. There are a number of other proposals which overlap existing Stack Exchange 1.0 sites but I've only included the ones where the link between proposal and 1.0 site was mostly unambiguous.

*Additional information*

- The primary source is definition phase comments on Area 51, but there isn't always a comment that clearly indicates a migration proposal. However, in some cases, it may be possible to corroborate a migration suggestion using other sources.
- If there is evidence that might indicate the site owner's support for a migration to Stack Exchange 2.0 I have added a reference and link after the name of the existing site.
- If I was able to find it, the copyright license has been indicated or linked; for a Creative commons license this is shown as "(cc) type". Some of the licenses (or lack thereof) may be incompatible with Stack Exchange 2.0. (*Note:* the sites listed appear to have a Creative Commons BY-SA 2.5 license on their RSS feeds regardless of what is displayed in the site HTML.)
- based on the [SharePoint Overflow welcome post](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family) some migrations may be limited to user accounts and not posts. However, the door is left open to importing some portion of the post content from the previous site after some time in beta.

I apologize for any errors I might have made. I also have not looked at every proposal on Area 51 so I've probably missed some.

**Phase: Launched** (beta seeded with migrated content)

- [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (*[proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electronics)*) - (*content migrated per [this answer here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/what-happened-to-chiphacker-com/65937#65937) and the [Area 51 proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electronics)*) - original: [Chiphacker](http://chiphacker.com) licensed (cc) [BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/)

**Phase: Launched** (beta *not* seeded with content from a pre-existing site)

- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) (*[proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics)*) - *(replaced older site at same URL, but was not a migration)* - migration originally proposed from [Physics Overflow](http://www.physicsoverflow.com/)

**Phase: Public Beta** (actually migrated)

- [Personal Finance and Money](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money)  (*[beta](https://money.stackexchange.com/)*) - [Basically Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)
- [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) - [OnStartups Answers](http://answers.onstartups.com/) (*announcement on [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business)*) - copyright OnStartups (standard © declaration)
- [Homebrewing (Beer, Wine, etc.)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc) (*[beta](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/)*) - [Brew Advice](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) (*[merger confirmation on Homebrewing Meta](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/merger-with-brewadvice/37#37)*)
- [User Experience](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-experience) (*[beta](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)*) - [UXExchange](http://uxexchange.com/) (*network site [renamed with a partial import of posts](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/rebranding-ui-to-ux-ux-exchange) but not user accounts. [1361 posts were migrated](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/is-the-merge-really-complete/254#254).*)
- [Jewish life and learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/) (*[beta](http://judaism.stackexchange.com)*) - [mi.yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (*migration of all users and content noted [meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) on new site*)

**Phase: Public Beta** (not seeded with migrated content)

- [Project Management](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management) (*[beta](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)*) - [Ask About Projects](http://www.askaboutprojects.com/) (*Area 51 [referral on original site](http://www.askaboutprojects.com/questions/2130/meta-about-the-future-of-askaboutprojects-com)*) - (cc) [BY-SA 3.0 US](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/) - (PM-SE was not seeded when its public beta opened, but there is a [site meta question about migration](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/are-the-questions-from-the-old-site-being-ported))
- [Skeptics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptic-exchange) (*[beta](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)*) - [Skeptic Exchange](http://www.skepticexchange.org/) (*referral to Area 51 on [home page](http://www.skepticexchange.org/)*) - (cc) [BY-NC-SA 2.0 UK](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/uk/) - (Skeptics-SE was not seeded when its public beta opened - there appears to be an [issue with license compatibility](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/migrating-questions-from-skeptic-exchange) - but the [domain will be transferred](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/redirecting-skepticexchange-org-traffic); some redirection is in place.)
- [SharePoint Overflow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint-overflow) (*[beta](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)*) - [SharePoint Overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) (*Area 51 [referral on original site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9270/how-can-i-help-sharepoint-overflow-move-to-stack-exchange-2-0-definition-phase)*) - (cc) [BY-SA  3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) - (SharePoint-SE was [seeded with users but not posts](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family) from the original site; it appears that some posts may be migrated later.)

**Phase: Commitment**

- [Game of Go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go) - [shidogo](http://shidogo.com/)

**Phase: Commitment** (proposed seed candidate offline/moved, migration unlikely)

- [EVE Online](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3371/eve-online) - [Skill Training Complete](http://skilltrainingcomplete.com/) (*referral to Area51 in [question on site](http://skilltrainingcomplete.com/questions/1046/what-do-you-think-of-stackexchange-2-0)*) - (cc) [BY-SA 3.0 US](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/) (*Skill Training Complete moved to different platform*)
- [Libraries](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12432/libraries) - [Unshelved Answers](http://answers.unshelved.com/) (*referral to Area 51 on [site owner's blog](http://www.unshelved.com/2010-9-2/Commit_to_Unshelved_Answers)*) - (cc) [BY-SA 2.5 US](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) (*Unshelved Answers has been closed.*)
- [Popular Natural Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4955/popular-natural-science) - [ScienceStack](http://science.stackexchange.com/) - (cc) [BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (*ScienceStack has been shutdown*)

**Closed on Area 51**

- [Gardening and Farming Organically](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85) - [Organic Green Fingers](http://organicgreenfingers.com/) (*Proposed seed candidate site also moved to different software. Area 51 referral on the original site is [now a dead link](http://organicgreenfingers.com/questions/297/are-you-interested-in-keeping-this-site-going), but also see the [comment on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63505/which-area-51-proposals-are-migration-proposals#comment-152074)*)

**Deleted from Area 51**

- [iPhone Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12572/iphone-development) - [EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://www.excbadaccess.com/) (*referral to Area 51 on [home page](http://www.excbadaccess.com/)*)
- [Crochet and Knit](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6040/crochet-and-knit) - [Stash Overflow](http://stashoverflow.com)

Comment: "Gardening and Farming Organically" - organicgreenfingers.com

Comment: @Ciaran I have added this site proposal to the list. When I saw it on Area 51, I didn't notice that Organic Green Fingers was an SE 1.0 site. I didn't have time to follow all the links so I just looked for comments like "this is a replacement for x".

Answer (score 5):

The decision to migrate a site doesn't usually come until *after* the proposal is nearing completion. Proposals are defined by the Area 51 community and there's no guarantee that the proposed site will develop in a way that is compatible with the SE 1.0 site. Also, the site itself has to have sufficient traffic to qualify as a Network site to be migrated. Finally, these are privately-owned systems and they are under no obligation to migrate their site, even if there is a compatible proposal. Most site owners take a wait-and-see stance when there is a similar site proposed.

Comment: However, since they also use the CC-by-SA license, the contents *could* be copied with attribution to the original site (just like all the SO-vampires do, only in this case, we're the good guys. right?)

Comment: @Tobias SE 1.0 had no requirement for the content to be CC-BY-SA. I don't know how many actually *did* use that license.

Comment: @balpha I didn't know that, I only checked http://mathoverflow.net

Comment: @balpha Concerning the ones moberley [listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63505/which-area-51-proposals-are-migration-proposals/63506#63506), they either have no license mentioned at all, or CC-BY-SA.

Comment: Just FYI, when there is no explicit license, the default state of published material is that all copyright is retained by the original author automatically (at least in the US). The "I am not a lawyer" yada yada applies.