# What happened to chiphacker.com?

Tags: discussion, support

Is chiphacker.com down for good or just for the time being?

Comment: this belongs on meta meta stackoverflow, or whatever that's called.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Yar, MSO is fine, since this is a SE2.0-related question.

Comment: It's down again, and now redirecting to electronics.stackexchange.com, which redirects to the Area51 electronics proposal.  Let it begin!

Answer (score 9):

It'll be back soon.  We just transferred the domain from the original owner to Stack Overflow in preparation for moving it to SE 2.0 this week (probably tomorrow).  We apparently missed something in the DNS transfer, so GoDaddy decided to advertise itself for a few hours...

edit: this is now live as a public beta -- http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I lost my original rep points from the site, as well as my questions. How can I get those back?

UPDATE: when I got redirected to my site, I saw my username existed on the site (onaclov2000) and when I tried to login it said I didn't have an account, so I clicked create, and now I don't see my previous questions. (Not as much worried about the points as I am finding my old questions linked to my account).

Comment: You were in the unfortunate position of having a Google OpenID and no email registered.  Google OpenIDs are per-domain, so when we changed the domain you couldn't log in, and because you had no email registered, you couldn't recover your account.  I've manually merged the two accounts so you should be good to go now.

Comment: Anyone else who experiences this problem should email team@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly shut me out, and now I'm redirected to area51. Not being able to get in to the site I had contributed at, and being given bogus instructions, is *very* annoying. (Joining area 51 and "commiting" produced no invitation.)

Comment: Try it again now

Comment: It's back up, now tagged as beta and redirecting to electronics.stackexchange.com. My web browser has now learned that Chiphacker.com is called "Down for Maintenance". The shutout appeared as I was trying to post a comment and I saw no notice the site wasn't ready before that.