# Can Draw3Cards be migrated to Stack Exchange 2.0 model?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0

[Draw3Cards](http://draw3cards.com/) is one of the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites. We are currently [deciding where Draw3Cards should be hosted](http://meta.draw3cards.com/questions/3/where-should-draw3cards-be-hosted) come April (once SE 1.0 is discontinued).

Is migration to Stack Exchange 2.0 an option? I've emailed Robert Cartaino about this, but haven't gotten a reply yet, so I thought to post this here.

Note that our site has some special features (implemented in javascript) that aren't found in SE 2.0 out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that a migration of the *site* can't happen now that [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) has launched. In Area51, the proposal would be closed as a duplicate of the existing site.

You can, however, migrate all the *content* and *users* to that site :)

That said, I'm a normal user exercising common sense and those are my worthless 0.02 cents.

Comment: Amm, Magic is not a role playing game. Not in the least.

Comment: @ripper whoops -- I'm really sorry. Wrong site, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you should create a proposal over at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and get your current users to follow the proposal, post sample questions and vote on them.

If enough of you do that you'll get the commitment stage very quickly. Progress from there depends on the reputation on existing Stack Exchange sites.

The reason I suggest this is that it's a clear demonstration of the support that the site has and, together with your existing site's traffic data, hopefully forms a good argument for the site to proceed.

Comment: I'm not saying that I won't this to happen, I just want to understand if it is, and how the procedure would go.

Comment: @ripper234 - in that case I'd e-mail Robert again. All you're going to get here is our best guesses.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extract from this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)

> If your site remains very active, we’d
> love to work with you to migrate it to
> the new, community-owned Stack
> Exchange platform. That would be the
> best thing that could happen to a
> Stack Exchange 1.0 site, in our
> opinion: that way your site can take
> advantage of our existing resources
> and expansive community.

So in a word yes; providing that you are receiving enough traffic for it to be a viable option.

I would imagine that it would have to come under StackExchange control & domain naming, unless it becomes a special case like http://askubuntu.com

Normally, I would suggest that you create a proposal on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) but as this would be a migration and not a new site it would probably be best to wait for a concrete response from a member of the Stack Overflow team.

Comment: All of the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites that have been migrated so far have gone through the proposal process at Area 51. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63505/which-area-51-proposals-are-migration-proposals

Comment: @Moberley - thanks for the clarification. I really wasn't 100% sure that is partly why I suggested waiting for someone from the SO Team to reply.  Thanks again though.